# Problema con algoritmo de sumatorias en Pseint

Tags: algoritmos, pseint

sumar x cantidad de números, dicha suma no rebase al número 30, decir cuántos números se sumaron en pseint.

necesito ayuda nose como realizar este algoritmo

```
para i=0 Hasta x hacer
                imprimir "Ingrese el ",i+1 " numero a sumar"
                leer num
                suma=suma+num
                imprimir "Total hasta ahora de la suma ",suma
                Finpara
            imprimir "Se sumaron ",i " numeros"
```

Intenté con éste código.

Comment: Antes que te caigan a negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta, lecturas altamente sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 En pocas palabras, edita la pregunta y agrega tantos detalles como sea posible para que tu pregunta sea exacta; describe lo que tienes en ese código, qué hace y hasta donde has llegado. Saludos.

Comment: *necesito ayuda nose como realizar este algoritmo* es una oración que no dice mucho. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿No funciona? ¿En qué falla? Y quizá te interese usar `x` en lugar de `i` en el último mensaje que imprimes.